# ORACLE DB dbf file related to which table?

Tags: database, oracle

I have a dbf files like:

```
undotbs01.dbf           10.16113281 GB
ENABLERS_DATA01.dbf     31.99998474 GB
```

How can I find that which tables are associated with the dbf files so that I can delete the corresponding data from the tables to reduce my dbf files disk consumption

Answer (score 2):

Tables aren't "associated" with a DBF file, they are associated with a tablespace which in turn is associated to one or more DBF files.

So you need to join the information from each table to the tablespace information, something like this:

```
select tbl.owner, 
       tbl.table_name, 
       df.tablespace_name,
       df.file_name
from all_tables tbl
  join dba_data_files df on df.tablespace_name = tbl.tablespace_name
order by 1,2;
```

If a tablespace has more than one datafile, you'll see that table more than once in the result (because of the join to `dba_data_files`) You cannot tell in which physical file the table's data actually lies.